# function of bounded variation and properties

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have to prove that if $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are  of  bounded variation so it is $f \cdot g$.

I want to use the definition to prove this but I don't  know how to maggiorate  $ \mid \sum_{i}{f \cdot g (x_{i})- f \cdot g (x_{i-1})}\mid$.

Any hint ?

Answer (score 0):

First note that

$|fg(x) - fg(y)| = |f(x)g(x) - f(y)g(y)| =$

$= |f(x)g(x) - f(x)g(y) + f(x)g(y) - f(y)g(y) | =$

$= |f(x)(g(x) - g(y)) + g(y)(f(x)- f(y))| \le $

$\le |f(x)||g(x) - g(y) | + |g(y)||f(x) - f(y) |$

Then use that $f$ and $g$ are bounded to conclud. Applied thus for the elements in the partition.

I hope that helps.